# How to utilize extended attributes for image preview?

Tags: linux, nautilus, cache, images, xattr

Is there any file browsers for Linux that cache image previews, just like Windows Explorer cache them to a file named `Thumbs.db`?

As in the latest ext3/4 filesystems, an inode can hold extended attributes, is it utilizied by any file browser? Well, the default 256B inode size may be too small to hold the preview, I can reformat it to get a bigger inode.

I'll be very glad to hear good news, because to refresh the previews for large images and video files are very slow in Nautilus, and noises from the harddisks ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nautilus uses `~/.thumbnails` normally. Lots of image viewers do generate thumbs there as well. In the `normal` sub-dir of my system most of the preview files are about 20 KiB in size. It's kinda disturbing that there're no either sqlite database in single file or cache hierarchy (like `f/ff/ffdcd558a…1e5200.png`) so some FSes could have poor performance looking up a file inside overgrown directory, though, but on the other hand, plain file storage is way simpler to handle inside bunch of different user programms, no mandatory demanding `sqlite` to be installed and most up-to-date FSes shouldn't have troubles with such plain files layout.

Problems with `xattr` resemble `sqlite`'s ones — extra complexity, limitations of FS support (according to wikipedia only ReiserFS and XFS handle arbitrary sizes, and EXT3,4 are limited to one block only which would mean 4 KiB mostly).

Comment: If Nautilus uses the `~/thumbnails`, why does it refresh the preview everytime I refresh the folder? Did I miss something?

Comment: @XièJìléi, a bug? Have you tried looking inside `~/.thumbnails`? What is there(?), is it updated(?), and on…

Comment: This is why we can't have nice things.

Comment: @bahamat, those "nice things" turn out tends to be Windows and Mac OS X. :)

Comment: I don't think that `sqlite` is extra complexity. Given that it's a very thoroughly tested piece of mission-critical-proven code, you'd be *very, very* hard pressed to develop something similarly stable and robust on your own. Sqlite, AFAIK, has been used in certified avionics applications. I'd wholeheartedly expect a homebaked thumbnail database solution to be brittle on broken sessions, power cycles, etc. These days sqlite represents a certain standard of performance, and it's not overly complex given how much work it'd take to have something equally robust.

Comment: @KubaOber, you're totally missing the point. It's not about writing own sqlites but about making all programs use it.

Comment: What's wrong with using a stable, robust piece of code that ensures that data will survive various corner cases that make people cry?

Comment: @KubaOber, not going tell ya.

Comment: All I know is that homebaked solutions fail, and when they do, people lose data and are upset. I have nothing to do with them or their code, merely enjoy its robustness in face of pulling the plug in various ways. Ultimately it's your choice what experience you give your users. Sqlite's benefits don't come merely from it being an SQL database, or perhaps they do, because it's a good implementation that strives to make the data survive at all costs, on various platforms. Given complexity of other frameworks, sqlite is like a free lunch with free dessert to boot.